# css layout - repeating backgrounds & overlapping images

Tags: html, css

I have been asked to design a page that looks like a stage.  The graphical elements are arranged like this:

```
[curtain repeat][left curtain][stage][right curtain][curtain repeat]
```

Left curtain, stage, and right curtain stay a fixed width in the middle of the screen.  If the browser is expanded horizontally, the outer "curtain repeats" need to be anchored to their respective curtains, but repeated toward the outside of the browser.  The effect is edge-to-edge curtain-stage-curtain.

Now, the other trick I need to implement is that the left and right curtains overlay or overlap the stage.  So if I position an element far to the right on the stage, a portion of the "right curtain" will overlap it, as if that element is partially behind the curtain.

I'm still learning css tricks, but I could use a jump start, as this is complicated beyond my experience level.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Post ur codes or give a fiddle.

Comment: Just to be clear- there's a stage with left and right curtains, and an additional curtain behind that is the full browser width? Seems an unlikely theatre setup ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stab at a basic structure with no images, only bkg colors:

http://jsfiddle.net/dtYKL/

HTML:

```
<div class="theatre">

    <div class="content">
        <div class="curtain left">left curtain</div>
        <div class="stage">stage!</div>
        <div class="curtain right">right curtain</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html{
    margin:0;            
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.theatre{
    width:100%;                
    background:#369; /* this is where you'd add your repeating curtain bkg */
}

.theatre .content{ /* this is your fixed-width stage content */
    position:relative;            
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    margin: 30px auto; /* centers the content */        
}

.content .curtain{ /* set your common styles, dimensions, positions for left + right curtains */
    position:absolute;    
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;    
}

.content .left.curtain{ /* position and add image for left curtain */
    left:0;
    top:0;    
    background:#963; /* this is where you'd add your left curtain image */
}

.content .right.curtain{ /* position and add image for right curtain */
    right:0;
    top:0;    
    background:#963; /* this is where you'd add your right curtain image */
}

.content .stage{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border-bottom:5px solid #000000; /* this will simulate a stage floor, you can use a solid bkg image if you want */
    box-sizing:border-box; /* this is so the border added above won't add to the div height */
    background-color:#888888; /* this is the stage background */    
    text-align:center;    
}
```

​
I nested all the content for this inside a div with class .theatre, this way you can specify a set height for your composition. If this is not necessary, feel free to remove that level of containment and just use 'body' as your repeating background curtain. Lemme know if you have any questions and good luck! :)